# Конфликт в gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

В проект добавлен `ActionBarSherlock`, когда пытаюсь подключить

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

То начинают вылетать ошибки в стиле: `Error:(118) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined`. Я так понимаю, что это происходит из-за того, что подключен `ActionBarSherlock`. Может можно написать какой-то  `exclude`, что бы не было конфликтов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не используйте `ActionBarShetlock`. Он уже 3 года, как не поддерживается. Весь функционал доступен в `SupportActionBar` из support-библиотеки

Comment: Это очень старый проект, который писала не я,  мне сюда просто нужно добавить новый функционал, по этому хочу узнать, можно ли добавить support:appcompat и support:design, и что бы при этом остался ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: @Lucky_girl, я понял, что в вашем случае переписывание кода, которое является правильным решением - не вариант, но, к сожалению, я не знаю другого варианта, и у меня есть подозрение, что поиск и имплементация другого решения займут даже больше времени, чем переписывание с `ActionBarShetlock` на `SupportActionBar `

Comment: может подскажите какие-то хорошие статьи, где можно почитать про миграцию с ActionBarShetlock на SupportActionBar? А то я боюсь, что начну сейчас менять и полетит весь проект.

Comment: @Lucky_girl, насколько я помню, нужно просто поменять имена классов, и, возможно, пространство имен атрибутов. Я не использовал статьи, мне все казалось достаточно очевидно

Comment: @Lucky_girl, быстро поискал тут https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20actionbarsherlock%20migrate%20to%20support  вроде по первой ссылке годное руководство, если можете читать игнглиш http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/